# Changing /etc/hosts with sed command

Tags: linux, bash, sed, cat

I'm trying to change /etc/hosts file with sed command , I use sudo to execute the following  command

```
 sudo sed 's/127.0.0.1 localhost/127.0.0.1 localhost mydomain.com/g' /etc/hosts |sudo cat > /etc/hosts
```

but this is the error that I get

```
-bash: /etc/hosts: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this (only once):

```
sudo sed -i 's/127.0.0.1 localhost/127.0.0.1 localhost mydomain.com/' /etc/hosts
```